# running two commands with delay in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

Here is my batch file

```
start /wait "C:\mcg_ia_tools-iqtool2\mydevenv.cmd"
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

I wish to create a simple batch file which runs the first file, waits until it finished executing and launches Visual Studio.

I have also tried using **delay** command, can't get it to work properly.

update: 
I have tried to do

```
call "C:\mcg_ia_tools-iqtool2\mydevenv.cmd"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

Here is my outpu, visual studio isn't being loaded

```
C:\Users\gdarmon\Desktop>call "C:\mcg_ia_tools-iqtool2\mydevenv.cmd"
Setting up the development environment...

C:\Users\gdarmon\Desktop>C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat""

C:\Users\gdarmon\Desktop>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to add a delay in a batch file is with the ping command.

```
Ping -l 1 -n 1 -w 5000 1.1.1.1 -4 1>nul 2>&1
```

The parameters you use are defined below:

```
-l = number of bytes in ping packet
-n = number of ping requests to send
-4 = for use of IPv4 (in case both are available)
-w = timeout in milliseconds
```

You can adjust the -w value 1000 = 1 second and the -n parameter to create a delay of almost any ammount.

The redirects at the end of the command hide the output from polluting the batch output.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show the `delay` command you used, and it isn't a standard command anyway.

You could possibly use `timeout` Type

```
timeout /?
```

from the prompt for details.

You don't say **why** you want the invisible delay.

Perhaps

```
call "C:\mcg_ia_tools-iqtool2\mydevenv.cmd"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

would suit your purpose better.

Comment: It takes time to load the *.cmd file so i need some delay

Comment: Your run-report shows `...cmd /k ...` which can only be in your `mydevenv.cmd` which you haven't posted, or perhaps you have a `start.bat` or `start.cmd` file - you should change the name of that file if this is so.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar script I wrote for a program I needed a virtual drive mounted before it ran so I added in a if exist command looking for the drive letter.

You could do something similar, the easiest way would be to have your mydevenv.cmd add a txt file to a temp folder.

A simple command like `echo finished > %temp%\mydevenvdone.txt`

Then have the main batch use these lines

```
:waiting
if exist %temp%\mydevenvdone.txt goto envdone
goto waiting
:envdone
del c:\temp\mydevenvdone.txt
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

So your batch would look like this:

```
@echo off
if exist %temp%\mydevenvdone.txt del %temp%\mydevenvdone.txt
start /wait "" "C:\mcg_ia_tools-iqtool2\mydevenv.cmd"
:waiting
if exist %temp%\mydevenvdone.txt goto envdone
goto waiting
:envdone
del c:\temp\mydevenvdone.txt
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

I added the extra del line at the start just incase you have to stop batch and it never cleans up.

Hope that's clear.

Comment: that does not do anything like expected it just opens some command line windows

Comment: Oops I forgot some "" in the start lines. Try adding those. They get me every time. I have updated the script above.